# I cant capture the response from Github api using Curl php

Tags: php, curl

```
<?php
session_start();
$url1 = "https://api.github.com/user?access_token=".$_SESSION['token'];
$json2 = 'Authorization: token '.$_SESSION['token'];
$ch1 = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch1,CURLOPT_URL,$url1);
curl_setopt($ch1,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch1,CURLOPT_HTTPGET, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type:application/json','Accept: application/json'));
curl_setopt($ch1,CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, true);

$result1 = curl_exec($ch1);
$result1 = json_decode($result1,true);
$headerSent = curl_getinfo($ch1, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT ); 
curl_close($ch1);
echo $headerSent;
echo $result1;
print_r($result1);


?>
```

The result is not displalyed. The headers are sent correctly. Please help guys I am stuck.

Comment: what is the value of $_SESSION['token'] to check ?

Comment: `var_dump($result1)`. What does it give? Is `curl_error` empty?

Comment: the url given is for github not twitter

Comment: @RamRaider sorry man its github.... my mistake on the Question

Comment: $_SESSION['token'] is my access_token @SonuR

Comment: Are your referring any article to capture the response from twitter api using Curl php ? If yes provide us.

Comment: var_dump() results NULL and yes curl_error is empty @Kisaragi

Comment: I am trying to retrieve a json object containing user information in exchange for accesstoken , I am getting the json if i directly send a get request from browser @Sonu R

Comment: try `$ch1 = curl_init($url1);` remove `curl_setopt($ch1,CURLOPT_URL,$url1);` and then `var_dump($result1)`

Comment: Did it and still nothing @Kisaragi

Comment: That's odd. Check your server logs (if available). Has CURL been disabled?

Comment: Got it guys , it needed an User-Agent header , I was missing that.... thank you